# Option to create new contact from pick list

Tags: android, android-contacts

My application wants a functionality of picking a contact from the 
phone contact, I have achieved this using the following intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, People.CONTENT_URI); 
startActivityForResult(intent, 001);
```

How do i start pick contact activity with an option to create a new contact from the pick list, similar to the one which is available in inbuilt Launcher appliation.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps passing in one of the extras listed in [Contacts.Intents.UI](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Contacts.Intents.UI.html). I'm mostly looking at `LIST_ALL_CONTACTS_ACTION` and `LIST_DEFAULT`.

Comment: do u mean like Intent intent = new Intent(LIST_ALL_CONTACTS_ACTION, People.CONTENT_URI).
This says activity is not found